# How far is the satellite from station A? How high is the satellite above the ground?

Tags: trigonometry

The path of a satellite orbiting the earth causes the satellite to pass directly over two tracking stations A and B, which are 75 mi apart. When the satellite is on one side of the two stations, the angles of elevation at A and B are measured to be 87.0° and 84.2°, respectively. (Round your answers to the nearest mile.)

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried?

Comment: i tired 75sin84.2 over sin 87

Comment: Why did you did this. Please edit your post to include your thoughts. Once I see what you tried, I'll show you m'y solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stations A and B form an acute triangle with the satellite. We will call the angle at the satellite C. The measure of angle C is 180°-87°-84.2°=8.8° (sum of angle measures in a triangle is 180°). The Law of Sines states that sinA/a = sinB/b = sinC/c, where a, b, and c are the sides opposite their respective angles. C=8.8°, A=87°, and c=75 miles. Plugging into the Law of Sines, a=c(sinA)(cscC)=75(sin87°)(csc8.8°)=489.5696028 miles.

Point D lies on segment AB such that CD is perpendicular to AB, and this segment will represent the satellite's distance from the ground.. Thus, ACD is a right triangle. Per right triangle trigonometry (SOHCAHTOA), sinA=opposite/hypotenuse=(length of CD)/489.5696028 miles. Length of CD=489.5696028(sin87°)=488.8986647 miles.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. First, have a look at Mathjax to improve your mathematical expressions. Second, on this site, we want to see the effort from the original poster before answering.

Comment: This would have been true is the satellite is between the two stations. It is on one side, so the solution Will be a bit different.